# How to use posted parameter in query in Pentaho CDE

Tags: pentaho

I made two CDE dashboards.

Dashboard(1) select ID and post it as parameter with URL to Dashboard(2).

Dashboard(2) show report using prpt component.

The Dashboard(2) has two parameters.They are ID(Custom Parameter) and Date(Simple Parameter).
ID is posted from Dashboard(1).
Date is selected by user using SelectComponent.

The Dashboard has SelectCompoment so that users can select Date.
Datasource is SelectDateQuery.
Date is calculated in sql over sqlJndi named SelectDateQuery.

Query is:

```
select Date from tablefoo
where ID= ${ID}
order by Date DESC
```

tablefoo is(I use MySQL Database):

```
|ID| Date|Score|
| 1|04-01|   90|
| 1|04-02|  100|
| 1|04-03|   80|
| 2|04-01|  100|
| 2|04-03|   70|
| 2|04-05|   60|
 …
```

If ID=1 is posted from Dashboard(1),I wish Select Component shows like bellow.

```
|04-03| 
|04-02|
|04-01|
```

But the SelectComponent is blank.

I checked MySQL log.
The query was:

```
select distinct Date from tablefoo
where ID= NULL
order by Date DESC
```

Parameter ID isn't used in the query.

What is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: refer this link find your mistake, and implement the same in your dashbord. http://pentaho-bi-suite.blogspot.in/2013/08/cascading-parameters-example-in-pentaho.html

Comment: To Working Hard   I set "Patameters"in properties on both Datasources and Component. It's works well. Thank you!